# Unable to launch Vimspector with CodeLLDB on MacOS

Tags: debugging, vim, rust

I'm trying to use [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#rust) plugin to debug my Rust code in Neovim. I got the basic configuration for `.vimspector.json`:

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "launch": {
      "adapter": "CodeLLDB",
      "filetypes": [ "rust" ],
      "configuration": {
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/my_project"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've downloaded CodeLLDB from VSCode and also directly from Vimspector, by using the command `:VimspectorInstall CodeLLDB`

I build my project and I try to launch it.

Unfortunately, I am stuck at this stage.
I can see my code, breakpoint, but nothing else.
Launching takes forever - as can be seen in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of Vimspector being launched]

I tried to fix it on my own for several hours, but I have totally no clue what can be missing in my configuration. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the architecture on your codelldb executable? It's displayed in the vimspector UI. I suspect the problem is that it's x86_64 when you're running Vimspector in a build of vim that's arm64. Run the `file` command on that file. [codelldb executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMzuX.png)

You'll want to update the vimspector packgage, so if you're using plugged then run `:PlugUpdate vimspector`. Then change directory into the vimspector package - there's a file called install_gadget.py. Run that `python3 install_gadget.py --enable-rust` to update the codelldb package. You'll see a version in arm64 install. Then you'll be good to go.